# como enviar eventos a distintos sockets en particulares

Tags: nodejs, typescript, socket.io

estoy buscando enviar eventos a distintos sockets, tengo el backend echo con nodejs y typescript y el frontend con react, todo funciona bien, cuando el cliente se conecta al socket, automáticamente se hace un update mediante mongoose que actualiza el socketid de mi modelo de datos, esto lo hago para tener el id del socket de cada usuario en la base de datos, mi idea es que cuando un usuario haga una acción, se envíen ciertos datos a ciertos usuarios,

```
const EmitterNewLike = async (_id: String, usr: IUsuario) => {
  const socket = getSocket();
  const publicacion: IPublicaciones | null = await Publicaciones.findById(
    _id
  ).populate({ path: "usuario" });
  socket.to([id, id, id, id ])emit("NEW_LIKE", publicacion, usr);
};
```

estoy buscando hacer algo como lo que se ve aquí, enviar mediante un `.to()`, un array de los id que van a recibir ese evento, obviamente esto no funciona, pero estoy buscando hacer algo similar para enviar eventos a ciertos usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear un modelo de suscripción; lo puedes hacer con socket.io.

Al establecer la conexión, dejas el room que viene por defecto y creas uno con el id del usuario:

```
socket.leave(socket.id);//leaving default room
socket.join(user_id);//joining to custom room
```

las suscripciones, obviamente están en la base de datos:

```
{ subscriptions : [
                     { id: "asdshkajh", channel_name: "channel1"}
                    ,{ id: "asdfsjsssjh", channel_name: "channel2"}
                   ]

}
```

haces el query a la base de datos para obtener las suscripciones y te unes al room de cada canal

```
subscriptions.forEach((channel)=>{
    socket.join(channel.id);
});
```

Ahora, para enviar una notificación a todos los suscriptores de un canal o seguidores, envías un mensaje a to propio room:

```
const room = socket.to(user_id);//user_id es el id de mi room
room.emit('algun evento');
```

Incluso puedes añadir mensajes privados y notificaciones a FCM(firebase cloud messaging). No hay pierde.

Puedes checar este ejemplo: [github.com](https://github.com/ulisesten/open-backend/blob/master/server/websockets/index)

Comment: con este metodo podria omitir esto: `try {
    const usuarior = await Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(tokenUser.id, { socket: socket.id });
    return usr
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null
  }` osea, me refiero a que puedo omitir la parte donde el usuario se conecta y yo actualizo el apartado `socketID` de mi db donde guardo el id del socket del usuario ?

Comment: Sí, así es. Utilizarías el id público con el que registraste tu usuario y ya no tendrías que llamar a la base de datos con cada evento.

Comment: genial, muy buena solución, tengo otra duda, estaba pensando que an vez de crear un array de `subscriptions` en la bd, utilizar los id de los amigos del usuario, esto es valido?

Comment: Sí, es  completamente válido.